# PyCharm autocomplete fails so show all options

Tags: python, pycharm

I have recently gotten into python and began using PyCharm, mainly for the code completion feature, as it helps me familiarize with new packages and libraries.

While working with discord.py, I have discovered that the autocompletion feature does not show all possible options.

To show an example, this code is valid and can be executed:

[image: Example 1]

However, if I attempt to use autocomplete to fill out line 11, neither user or name is offered.

Example 2
[image: Example 2]

Example 3
[image: Example 3]

Oddly enough, the autocomplete does work for a large portion of the package though, as shown here:

[image: Example 4]

I have struggled for a long time trying to figure out why this happens. I have made sure I'm using the correct interpreter (discord.py is shown in the installed packages) and I have enabled "Collect run-time types information for code insight" under Python Debugger in Settings, as I have read that this might help.

I'll be thankful for any insight into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.Client` uses [`__getattr__`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v0.16.12/discord/client.py#L291) to handle attribute lookup for the `user` attribute dynamically. `__getattr__` is fundamentally incompatible with the kind of static analysis PyCharm uses for autocompletion.

I'd probably just live with PyCharm not being able to find this attribute. If you want to do something about it anyway, writing [type stubs](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules) might help (or they might go out of sync with the implementation and cause more problems), or you could see if discord.py would accept a pull request to use properties instead of `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` for the attribute forwarding they're doing here.